# How to modify this python script to execute php file when the beacon shows/doesn't on scanner?

Tags: python, bluetooth, iot

We ran this and it works fine. It shows the beacons but we need it to execute a different php files depending if it the beacons show or doesn't on the scanner.

We're using Raspberry Pi 3 model B as the scanner and the os is raspbian buster.

```
import ScanUtility
import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez

#Set bluetooth device. Default 0.
dev_id = 0
try:
    sock = bluez.hci_open_dev(dev_id)
    print ("\n *** Looking for BLE Beacons ***\n")
    print ("\n *** CTRL-C to Cancel ***\n")
except:
    print ("Error accessing bluetooth")

ScanUtility.hci_enable_le_scan(sock)
#Scans for iBeacons
try:
    while True:
        returnedList = ScanUtility.parse_events(sock, 10)
        for item in returnedList:
            print(item)
            print("")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Any ideas? We are clueless when it comes to python.

Answer (score 1):

Where you do

```py
print(item)
print("")
```

you can add:

```py
os.system("php phps/file.php")
```

add

```py
import os
```

to the top of your script.